# Place the first value of Column B in Column C if Column A has same names in python pandas with loop

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements, logic

I have the following data set in python,

**Input**

[image]

I want to bring the first value of Column B that belongs to column Column A for a unique A value to be pasted in Column C.

For eg. value a in Column A has ABC, XYZ, and PQR, so in column C I want ABC, ABC, ABC
Similarly for value b in Column A.

**Expected Output:**

[image]

I tried the following code in python.

```
df['C']=None
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['A'][i]==df['A'][i+1] and df['C'][i]==None:
        df['C'][i]=df['B'][i]
        if df['A'][i]==df['A'][i+1] and df['C'][i]!=None
```

I am stuck how to proceed with that.
I will be really grateful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df["C"] = df[df.index.isin(df.reset_index().groupby("A")["index"].first().to_list())]["B"]
df["C"].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```